# How to make a download progress indicator in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack

I am learning Kotlin and Jetpack Compose and I am doing a download handler :
My goal is to make a progress bar with percentage of completion.

I tried something that works almost well but I don't understand why every print is printed twice.

```
class AndroidDownloader(context: Context) : DownloaderInterface {

    private val downloadManager = context.getSystemService(DownloadManager::class.java)!!
    var downloadId by mutableStateOf(0L)
    var isFinishedDl by mutableStateOf(true)
    var progress by mutableStateOf(0)

    override fun downloadFile(ctx: Context, url: String): Long {
        val request = DownloadManager.Request(url.toUri())
            .setMimeType("*/*")
            .setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI) 
     .setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED)
            .setTitle("demodatabase.db")
            .addRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer <token>")
            .setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "demodatabase.db")
        return downloadManager.enqueue(request)
    }

    fun handleProgress() {
        println("start handleProgress...")
        isFinishedDl = false

        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default).launch {
            while (!isFinishedDl) {
                val q = DownloadManager.Query().setFilterById(downloadId)
                val cursor = downloadManager.query(q)
                if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    val colStatus = cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS)
                    if (colStatus >= 0) {
                        when (cursor.getInt(colStatus)) {
                            DownloadManager.STATUS_FAILED -> {isFinishedDl = true }
                            DownloadManager.STATUS_PAUSED -> { }
                            DownloadManager.STATUS_PENDING -> { }
                            DownloadManager.STATUS_RUNNING -> {
                                print("statusRunning - ")
                                val colIdTotal =  cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_TOTAL_SIZE_BYTES)
                                if (colIdTotal >= 0) {
                                    val total = cursor.getLong(colIdTotal)
                                    if (total > 0L) {
                                        val colIdBytes = cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_BYTES_DOWNLOADED_SO_FAR)
                                        if (colIdBytes >= 0) {
                                            val downloaded = cursor.getLong(colIdBytes)
                                            progress = (downloaded * 100L / total).toInt()
                                            println("dl progress... $progress%")
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL -> {
                                progress = 100
                                println("finished - dl progress: $progress%")
                                isFinishedDl = true
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    isFinishedDl = true
                }
//                cursor.close() // not sure about this line
                delay(1000L) // delay to avoid dozens of line printing
            }
            println("end handleProgress.")
        }
    }
}
```

And here are the prints of this code :

```
I/System.out: start handleProgress... 
I/System.out: progress : 0 
I/System.out: pending... 0% 
I/System.out: statusRunning - dl progress... 0% 
I/System.out: statusRunning - dl progress... 0% 
I/System.out: statusRunning - dl progress... 27% 
I/System.out: statusRunning - dl progress... 27% 
I/System.out: statusRunning - dl progress... 43% 
I/System.out: statusRunning - dl progress... 43% 
I/System.out: statusRunning - dl progress... 54% 
I/System.out: statusRunning - dl progress... 54% 
I/System.out: statusRunning - dl progress... 67% 
I/System.out: statusRunning - dl progress... 67% 
I/System.out: statusRunning - dl progress... 88% 
I/System.out: onDownloadCompleted 
I/System.out: Download with ID 136 finished! 
I/System.out: finished - dl progress: 100% 
I/System.out: end handleProgress.
```

As you can see, every step is printed twice, and I don't get why...

Can anyone help me?

*A second step would be to render this in the UI with Jetpack Compose, I'll try that after solving the first issue.*

Comment: I should mention I test the download with the url "http://speedtest.ftp.otenet.gr/files/test10Mb.db", which give me a 10Mb file, taking 4-5 seconds to complete.